# Fastest or best way to read from SSLSocket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, https, serversocket

I'm running a multithreaded minimalistic http(s) server (not a web server though) that accepts connections on three server sockets: local, internet and internet-ssl.

Each socket has a so timeout of 1000ms (might be lowered in the future).

The worker threads read requests like this:

```
byte[] reqBuffer = new byte[512];
theSocket.getInputStream().read(reqBuffer);
```

The problem now is that with the newly implemented ssl socket the problem with the 1/n-1 record splitting technique arises. Also some clients split in other strange ways when using ssl (4/n-4 etc.) so I thought I might just perform multiple reads like this:

```
byte[] reqBuffer = new byte[512];
InputStream is = theSocket.getInputStream();
int read = is.read(reqBuffer, 0, 128); // inital read - with x/n-x this is very small
int pos = 0;
if (read > 0) {
   pos = read;
}
int i = 0;
do {
   read = is.read(reqBuffer, pos, 128);
   if (read > 0) {
      pos += read;
   }
   i++;
} while(read == 128 && i < 3); // max. 3 more reads (4 total = 512 bytes) or until less than 128 bytes are read (request should be completely read)
```

Which works with browsers like firefox or chrome and other clients using that technique.

Now my problem is that the new method is much slower. Requests to the local socket are so slow that a script with 2 seconds timeout times out requesting (I have no idea why). Maybe I have some logical problem in my code?

Is there a better way to read from a SSL socket? Because there are up to hundreds or even a thousand requests per second and the new read method slows down even the http requests.

Note: The ssl-socket is not in use at the moment and will not be used until I can fix this problem.

I have also tried reading line for line using a buffered reader since we are talking about http here but the server exploded running out of file descriptors (limit is 20 000). Might have been because of my implementation, though.

I'm thankful for every suggestion regarding this problem. If you need more information about the code just tell me and I will post them asap.

**EDIT:**
I actually put a little bit more thought into what I am trying to do and I realized that it comes down to reading HTTP headers. So the best solution would be to actually read the request line for line (or character for character) and stop reading after x lines or until an empty line (marking the end of the header) is reached.
My current approach would be to put a BufferedInputStream around the socket's InputStream and read it with an InputStreamReader which is "read" by a BufferedReader (question: does it make sense to use a BufferedInputStream when I'm using a BufferedReader?).
This BufferedReader reads the request character for character, detects end-of-lines (\r\n) and continues to read until either a line longer than 64 characters is reached, a maximum of 8 lines are read or an empty line is reached (marking the end of the HTTP header). I will test my implementation tomorrow and edit this edit accordingly.

**EDIT:**
I almost forgot to write my results here: It works. On every socket, even faster than the previously working way. Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up implementing it like this:

```
List<String> requestLines = new ArrayList<String>(6);
InputStream is = this.cSocket.getInputStream();
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, Config.REQUEST_ENCODING);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

/* read input character for character
* maximum line size is 768 characters
* maximum number of lines is 6
* lines are defined as char sequences ending with \r\n
* read lines are added to a list
* reading stops at the first empty line => HTTP header end
*/
int readChar; // the last read character
int characterCount = 0; // the character count in the line that is currently being read
int lineCount = 0; // the overall line count
char[] charBuffer = new char[768]; // create a character buffer with space for 768 characters (max line size)

// read as long as the stream is not closed / EOF, the character count in the current line is below 768 and the number of lines read is below 6
while((readChar = br.read()) != -1 && characterCount < 768 && lineCount < 6) {
    charBuffer[characterCount] = (char) readChar; // fill the char buffer with the read character
    if (readChar == '\n' && characterCount > 0 && charBuffer[characterCount-1] == '\r') { // if end of line is detected (\r\n)
        if (characterCount == 1) { // if empty line
            break; // stop reading after an empty line (HTTP header ended)
        }
        requestLines.add(new String(charBuffer, 0, characterCount-1)); // add the read line to the readLines list (and leave out the \r)
        // charBuffer = new char[768]; // clear the buffer - not required
        characterCount = 0; // reset character count for next line
        lineCount++; // increase read line count
    } else {
        characterCount++; // if not end of line, increase read character count
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*http(s) server (not a web server though)*"?

Comment: @Bruno Well it is not serving websites to browsers or something like that. It implements only a very small part of the HTTP protocol and does some dirty (but reliable) and fast request parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Reading about all this streams and readers led me to the conclusion that I should rely on the protocol I'm dealing with. Since I only need the HTTP header this should be a pretty easy task (well reading the content after processing the content-length header would not be that much of a problem either).
I edited my original post to reflect this.

Comment: In general, the assumption you initially made about reading a fixed number of bytes to get an HTTP request (even if it's just the headers) is wrong. You should indeed detect the end of lines for the header (and use the content-length or the chunked transfer encoding for the entity).

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely slower as you are waiting for the other end to send more data, possibly data it is never going to send.

A better approach is you give it a larger buffer like 32KB (128 is small) and only read once the data which is available.  If this data needs to be re-assembled in the messages of some sort, you shouldn't be using timeouts or a fixed number of loops as read() is only guaranteed to return one byte at least.

Comment: Yes this is probably the problem and also why I stop reading after the last read did not read the full 128 bytes. I could also read like 128 / 384 bytes in two reads but I need at least two because of the record splitting.
As far as I understood the timeout limits the time that read waits and does not increase it or am I wrong?
The fixed number of loops is there to limit the total size read to 512 bytes.
I'm only reading 512 bytes of the request in total (as you can see from my buffer size) because all the information I need is contained within those 512 bytes (if not the request is invalid).

Comment: If you want to read 512 bytes, why don't you read 512 bytes from the start?

Comment: @Kazuo, you should always assume you'll need multiple reads anyway. It's more visibly necessary with TLS record splitting, but that would be required for plain TCP too anyway. Don't make any assumptions as to how the records are going to be split (1/n-1, 4/n-4, 0/n, ...), and don't assume 3 is enough. Just read until it's over, or use a time out. Using a `BufferedInputStream` might help, but don't forget to close it, though.

Comment: @Kazuo DataInputStream as readFully to read a specific number of bytes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I did but in one read.
DataInputStream seems to work but the 1s socket timeout does not seem to be enough. If I remove the timeout I reach the file descriptor limit of 20000 in like 10-15 seconds. Same problem with BufferedInputStream. And yes I did close it after reading.

Comment: @Bruno It worked for months. The only reason for me to change this is the ssl socket. BufferedInputStream seems to block for too long. But still there is a huge amount of reads that time out.

Comment: BufferedInputStream doesn't block for any longer than the socket's input stream itself, or anything else you can wrap around it. If you're getting a huge number of timeouts, either the peer has a problem or your read timeout is too short, probably both. One second is certainly absurdly short.

Comment: @Bruno I don't know what is so special about BufferedInputStream that you think it needs any more closing than anything else. Actually you don't need to close it at all: just close the output stream.

Comment: @EJP Internal request processing takes around 50-100ms and the overall time to complete an usual request is around 300-500ms. I set this limit so "low" to avoid slow clients blocking worker threads. When I said I get a lot of read timeouts we're talking about 2-10 of a few hundred. I'm still experimenting with the time limit, though.

Comment: @Kazuo You should have a protocol when the read time limit never applies under ideal conditions.  It should only apply if there is a network failure or poor performance. I would look at handling requests faster 500ms is eternity for a computer, your system can perform billions of operations in that time. You can send a packet to Tokyo and back from almost anywhere in the world in less time.

Comment: @EJP, you're right, I just meant this in the context of the related paragraph in the question "*[...] server exploded running out of file descriptors*". I'd guess some I/O streams weren't closed properly one way or another.

Answer (score 3):

You should *certainly* wrap a BufferedInputStream around the SSLSocket's input stream.

Your technique of reading 128 bytes at a time and advancing the offset is completely pointless. Just read as much as you can at a time and deal with it. Or one byte at a time from the buffered stream.

Similarly you should certainly wrap the SSLSocket's output stream in a BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: Well I would not consider it pointless since it works as intended, just way too slow. I will try your suggestions. Reading one byte at a time seems pretty slow. Would you mind suggesting an implementation?

Comment: Extra code to do the same thing you were already doing is always pointless. `BufferedInputStream.read()` isn't slow, because of the buffering.

Comment: @EJC Yes it might do the same, but I just needed to be able to handle splitted requests (and it allows me to do that, just not fast enough). But of course you are right in saying that this was not a good solution. But after all, that is why I came here and asked this question. Thanks for your advise I think I'm getting somewhere.